# Why can I delete write-protect file(hard link) in my own directory?

Tags: linux, unix

The process is like the following `root` is a file whose owner is `root`:

```
~$ ln root another_file
~$ ls -l another_file
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root 0 Jan 24 15:48 another_file
~$ rm another_file
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file `another_file'? y
~$ ls -l another_file
```

However, this won't work..

```
~$ ln root another_file
~$ chmod a+w another_file
chmod: changing permissions of `another_file': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: This question belongs to serverfault

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of the unix priciples. It is perfectly all right. The reason simply is that you have write permission to the directory itself. That grants you control over all entries contained in that directory. You'd have a huge problem otherwise. Note that this rule is not limited to hard links, but to every entry in general.

Comment: Thanks, but why I can't change the permission of that file?

Comment: Because it is not your file. It belongs to root. You have no write permission to that file. Put it this way: you have the right to control the _existance_ of the file, since this is _your_ directory and the nodes existance is on directory level. But you cannot change any _detail_ of the file since those details are part of the file, not the directory level.

Comment: The phrase "node contained in the directory" is not well defined, since inodes do not exist in a directory.  If `/tmp/foo/bar` and `/tmp/qux/baz` are links to the same inode, in which directory is the inode contained?  (Perhaps I misunderstand your usage of the word "node".)